# Все ли пунктуационные знаки на своих местах?

Tags: пунктуация

> Впрочем, архитектура – единственный вид искусства, что разворачивает
>   своё волшебство в метрическом пространстве, то есть для того, чтобы
>   его познать, необходимо его прожить, как минимум – измерить шагом.

Хочу точку с запятой перед "то есть". Объяснить хотенье не могу.

Может, вообще - двоеточие треба? О_о

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Впрочем, архитектура – единственный вид искусства, ч**то разворачивает своё волшебство в метрическом пространстве:  для того чтобы его познать,** необходимо его прожить, как минимум – измерить шагом.**

Двоеточие вполне может заменить пояснительный союз ТО ЕСТЬ, и запятых меньше.

**По поводу который/что.**

Союзное слово ЧТО не согласуется с определяемым существительным в роде, в отличие от КОТОРЫЙ, а в предложении три существительных разного рода: архитектура, вид, искусство.

Похожий пример: Музыка – единственный вид искусства, который отражает нашу жизнь посредством звуков.

Отражает жизнь музыка (ж.р.), а согласование приходится делать в м.р.

Comment: Таким образом, в данном предложении *что* непонятно к какому слову относится, а *который* не оставляло бы места для сомнений. Не так ли?

Comment: Не совсем так. Используя местоимение ЧТО,  мы освобождаем себя от обязанности согласования в м.р ил в ср.р., учитывая, что речь идет об архитектуре (ж.р.).

Comment: Еще я прочитала у Розенталя, что с.с. ЧТО придает  предложению эмоциональность: Виктор Гюго ворвался в классический и скучноватый век как ураганный ветер, как вихрь, что несет потоки дождя....

Comment: Понимаете, здесь случай, описанный @Alex_ander: можно добавить слово *тот*: как **тот** вихрь, что несет потоки дождя.

Comment: По поручению уважаемого редактора спрашиваю: почему "измерить шагом" Вы не исправили на "измерить шагами". Считаете приемлемым?

Comment: В Нацкорпусе авторы только *шагами* измеряют...

Comment: Да,  измеряют шагами. И в словаре тоже: ШАГ 6. Расстояние между стопами ног при движении как мера длины. Отмерить шагами десять метров. Но в этот текст "шаги" никак не вписываются.  Шаг здесь что-то вроде инструмента. Например, мы говорим "измерить линейкой", но не "линейками" же. Мне фраза  и сначала не показалась неверной, а  сейчас я думаю, что в таком тексте используется переносное, обобщенное значение выражения. Я бы оставила - "шагом".

Comment: Инструмент - ноги. А мерить комнату (землю) шагами — это тоже в переносном смысле, не об измерениях речь.

Comment: Какие же ноги? Это расстояние. Возьмите палку, равную длине шага, и измерьте  заданную длину палкой, но только не палками. И вообще, как можно метрическое пространство  мерить шагами, будто это комната какая.

Comment: Палка - предмет, ноги - тоже предмет, а шаг - одно движение ног или единица измерения

Comment: "Мерить шагами" — также устойчивый оборот, в смысле *шагать*.

Comment: Умом Россию не понять, Аршином общим не измерить:. АРШИН,  Старинная русская мера длины, равная 0,711 метра. Шаг ЗДЕСЬ как аршин, то есть мера длины.

Comment: Аршин - устаревший инструмент для измерения длины (Википедия)

Comment: В общем,  отмерить шагами (шагая) -  это разговорное, неточное выражение, правильно - измерить в чём ( в метрах, в шагах,  в единицах  длины) или  чем (линейкой, аршином, шагом  - инструментом). И еще вопрос: как вы на слух воспринимаете  - измерить шагами?  Неужели оно не кажется вам сугубо практичным, хозяйственным, никак не отнесенным к высокой философии?

Comment: Спасибо, Жасминчик!

Comment: Измерять можно (1) в единицах измерения (2) инструментом (3) действием. Автор явно не о единицах измерения ведет речь. Шаг - не инструмент, а действие. Сравните: измерять линейкой — разрушать кувалдой; измерять шагами — разрушать ударами (**мн.ч**)

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, "что" здесь неуместно.

По-моему, точка перед "то есть" — самый удачный вариант, двоеточие хуже, запятая — еще хуже, но запрета нет. Если ставить двоеточие, то надо убрать "то есть": двоеточие само по себе означает "то есть".

Измеряют шагами (мн.ч.).

Comment: Ну, *что* и *который* - синонимы, а стилистику выбирает автор. А точка с запятой очень сильно смыслово приближена к точке, но всё ж не рубит предложение. Я думаю...

Comment: Поискал в Нацкорпусе: "единственный, который"  — есть, "единственный, кто" — есть,  "единственный, что" — нет (в нужном нам смысле)

Comment: Спроси у Жасминчика, почему она считает возможным оставить *измерить шагом*.