# Можно ли так писать: "единственный, что ..."?

Tags: спп, союзы

На нашем сайте [обсуждалась](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/437273/%D0%92%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%85) фраза:

**Впрочем, архитектура – единственный вид искусства, что разворачивает своё волшебство в метрическом пространстве.**

Утверждалось, что *что* и *который* взаимозаменяемы.

А мне продолжает казаться, что слово *что* здесь неуместно. Результаты поиска в Нацкорпусе как-будто подтверждают мою правоту: "единственный, который" — есть, "единственный, кто" — есть, "единственный, что" — не найдено (в нужном нам смысле).

Помогите разобраться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Действительно, данном случае употребление "что" выглядит неуместным, хотя проблема заключена не в сочетаемости "*единственный + что*". Дело в том, что данное местоимение в качестве сокращения от разделённого местоимения "**тот... что**" обычно служит для указания, ссылки на что-то, и такое сокращение возможно лишь в немногих случаях простого *указания на что-то хорошо известное*, обычно это связано с топонимикой. Например (условно): "*знаменитый дуб, что у развилки дорог на Москву и Киев...*" Утверждение же, что "который" можно заменить на "что" в произвольных случаях жизни, не имеет достаточных оснований хотя бы потому, что "**который**" шире и может присоединять *новое* для читателя утверждение (здесь "волшебство", о котором читатель вряд ли слышал). Для того, чтобы исправить исходное предложение и обойтись без "который", нужно  употребить "тот... что" в полной форме, при этом значение утверждаемого может несколько измениться: "единственность" будет напоминаться читателю как нечто ему известное и само собой разумеющееся (общеизвестно и не подлежит сомнению, что архитектура разворачивается в метрическом пространстве - "волшебство" придётся убрать из соображений "не всеобщей" его очевидности):

> Впрочем, архитектура и есть **тот** единственный вид искусства, **что**
>   разворачивается в метрическом пространстве.

Comment: Вы сумели логически доказать то, что подсказывала мне интуиция!

Answer (score 2):

В Вашем предложении слово что относится не к слову единственный, а к слову вид.

Вид, что разворачивает...

Замена слова который на что правомерна.
["Художник, что рисует дождь..." "Что" или "который"?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/417053/%D0%A5%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%8C-%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9)

Также слово что может являться синонимом слова который: https://www.google.ru/url?q=http://www.classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-synonyms-term-31325.htm&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwiv49-2vP3YAhXJ1qQKHXprC5gQFjABegQIERAB&usg=AOvVaw1S8QfKmcbQ6RaNLmeCxBIS

Слово *что* вместо *который* используется в разговорной речи, просторечии, а также ориентированных на эти сферы языка жанрах письменной, особенно стихотворной речи. Употребление слова *что* вместо *который* зависит только от сферы употребления, но не от одушевлённости или неодушевлённости существительных. (http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=205522)

Answer (score 2):

В подтверждение другого ответа приведу несколько цитат с подобным употреблением.

> Я пошлю двуколку к вечернему семичасовому поезду – это единственный,
>   что останавливается здесь (Артур Конан Дойл).
>
> Ночь забвения — единственная, что длится без перерывов (Андрей
>   Столяров).
>
> Отыскивать себя в забытом прошлом и в неизвестном будущем — вот роль
>   единственная, что имеет смысл ("Петербургский театральный журнал").
>
> У меня очень много религий, а та единственная, что все их объединит,
>   сложится лишь в течение моей жизни (Э.Канетти).
>
> Эта моцартовская опера, по-моему, единственная, что довольно часто
>   шла в Москве (журнал "Музыкальная жизнь").